# (closed) Python: No module named cv2, unless first cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Tags: python, macos, opencv, module, path

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) and installed OpenCV on my computer (Mac, OS X Yosemite). However, it works only if I first

```
    cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

There is the cv2.so file.

However, when I don't change the direction (for example when I try to run a program - I don't know if I can change the direction inside a python script -- and I don't know what's the right way to google it to find out), I get the

```
    ImportError: No module named cv2.
```

How do I fix that (or change the direction inside python program, if that is possible / I have tried sys.path.append('path') though)? Thanks.

Comment: Which command are you executing from the terminal to run your code?

Comment: I write import cv2, and it shows the mistake 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2

Comment: Yeah, but which python are you opening? Try `python2.7` instead of `python` when opening python from terminal

Comment: I just tried with python2.7 instead of python and it gives the same error.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to append `~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to your PATH. You're probably doing it wrong

Comment: I tried to run this, but I get the same error:

    import sys
sys.path.append("~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/")

import cv2

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: Do not use `~/` . Use `/home/YOURNAME/...` . To check full path, go to `~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and type the command `pwd`. Copy this path and append it to path.

Comment: Wow, it worked, thank you so much! :))